# Хранение ключей и значений в словаре

Tags: python

Мне нужно в словарь записать пары ключ и значение.

Но в ключах есть одинаковые значения и программой затирается предыдущее значение, а мне нужно, чтобы присутствовали все записи.

Как мне поступить?

Имеется фрагмент:

```
result = get_sports(["Ронни О'Салливан - снукер", 'Магнус Карлсен - шахматы', 'Марк Селби - снукер'])
for key in sorted(result):
    print(key + ':', ', '.join(sorted(result[key])))
```

Нужно после процедуру обработки для получения:

> ```
> снукер: Марк Селби, Ронни О'Салливан
> шахматы: Магнус Карлсен
> ```

---

Спасибо большое! Помогло! Адаптировал под функцию.
Осталась только одна проблемка.
Мой код

```
def get_sports(lines):
    result=dict()
    for sport in lines:
        item = sport.split('-')
        result[item[1].strip()] = result.setdefault(item[1].strip(), list()) + [item[0].strip()]
    return result

    print(get_sports(['спортсмен1 - спорт1']))
```

выводит

> {'спорт1': ['спортсмен1']}

а требуется

> {'спорт1': {'спортсмен1'}}

как получить фигурные скобки вместо квадратных?
иначе тест не проходит

Comment: Очевидно, в качестве значения использовать список

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sports = ["Ронни О'Салливан - снукер", 'Магнус Карлсен - шахматы', 'Марк Селби - снукер']
dictionary = dict()
for sport in sports:
    item = sport.split('-')
    dictionary[item[1].strip()] = dictionary.setdefault(item[1].strip(), list()) + [item[0].strip()]

for sport, names in dictionary.items():
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(sport, ', '.join(names)))
```

`set()` вместо `list()`:

```
sports = ["Ронни О'Салливан - снукер", 'Магнус Карлсен - шахматы', 'Марк Селби - снукер']
dictionary = dict()
for sport in sports:
    item = sport.split('-')
    dictionary[item[1].strip()] = dictionary.setdefault(item[1].strip(), set())
    dictionary[item[1].strip()].add(item[0].strip())

for sport, names in dictionary.items():
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(sport, ', '.join(names)))
```

Comment: всё норм! Спасибо большое за помощь начинающим!

Comment: @fanat [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)